# Разделить виды трафика (vpn от не-vpn)

Tags: windows, vpn

Приветствую всех знающих и неравнодушных.

Запросы снаружи с ip-адреса 91.227.16.11 на порт 90 перенаправляются во внутрь на 192.168.0.15 порт 8888. Там сидит локальный Аппач. Перенаправление настроено в роутере.

Когда на локальной машине Windows10 192.168.0.15 запускаю VPN, то запрос к Аппачу извне уже не проходит.
Нужно как-то разделить эти два вида трафика: чтобы трафик с 91.227.16.11 на локальную машину ходил без vpn, а всё остальное - через vpn.

Подозреваю, нужно прописывать маршруты на локальной машине, но сам не могу сообразить, как это должно выглядеть. Не так много опыта. Помогите, пожалуйста, инструкциями.

Answer (score 1):

Подключение перестаёт устанавливаться, потому что возникает асимметричная маршрутизация: ответный трафик с сервера до IP-адреса подключающегося начинает маршрутизироваться через VPN, с IP-адреса сервера VPN, а не адреса вашего сервера.
Пакет даже может дойти до получателя (зависит от настроек VPN-сервера), но его компьютер не может связать запрос и ответ из-за несовпадения IP-адресов.

Необходимо в Apache настроить bind к физическому (не-VPN) интерфейсу либо адресу, и убедиться, что у вас сохраняется маршрут по умолчанию через не-VPN-интерфейс, но при этом имеет метрику выше.

> чтобы трафик с 91.227.16.11 на локальную машину ходил без vpn, а всё остальное - через vpn

Если имеется в виду, что указанный адрес — IP клиента, то это совсем просто — добавьте маршрут до 91.227.16.11/32 через физический интерфейс, Apache перенастраивать не потребуется.

Comment: ValdikSS, Да, 91.227.16.11 это клиент, трафик к которому должен ходить в обход vpn-сети.
Вы имеете в виду добавить маршрут route add 91.227.16.11 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1 metric 1? Добавил. Получилось так:
91.227.16.11  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.19     36
Он стоит первый в списке. ip 192.168.1.1 - это адрес шлюза, а 192.168.1.19 — ip Аппача.
В таком виде не работает.

Comment: Должно работать, проверяйте дампом трафика, что конкретно не так.